# Add button is not working in selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate some process, while I am not able to add a button in python selenium. I have tried with
`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnAddCust"]').click()` and `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ttAddCustomer"]').click()`
but that doesn't work.[enter image description here][1]

check the link for the source code :
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbYzr.png

Comment: Could you share the website link you're working on?

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I've solved that out. There were multiple iframes so i have to switch to that frame :)